# how to use react published npm component in angular

Tags: reactjs, angular, npm, plugins, components

I have created simple react component and published to NPM registry. its working fine with react but I want to use same plugin in angular project its showing below error.

Custom plugin : https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactcustomplugin

error while importing plugin to angular module.

```
npm i reactcustomplugin
```

appmodule.ts

```
import SayHello from 'reactcustomplugin';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SayHello] })  ==> getting below error
     ,
```

Type '({ name }: { name: string; }) => Element' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type | ModuleWithProviders<{}>'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

obviously, you can't use the package written in react for angular or anything else ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).